# leetcode.com - Remove Element - why doesn't i++ work?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am working on an algorithm from leetcode.

here is the description:

> Given an array and a value, remove all instances of that value in
>   place and return the new length. Do not allocate extra space for
>   another array, you must do this in place with constant memory. The
>   order of elements can be changed. It doesn't matter what you leave
>   beyond the new length. Example: Given input array nums = [3,2,2,3],
>   val = 3 Your function should return length = 2, with the first two
>   elements of nums being 2.

My question is based on the following code:

```
var removeElement = function(nums, val) {

    var count = 0;

    for(i=0; i<nums.length; i++){

        if(nums[i] == val) {
            nums.splice(i,1);
            i--;
        }
    }

};
```

My question is, why does decrementing with i-- work but incrementing with i++ does not work?

A situation in which my answer is not accepted is when the input array is [3, 3], and the value is 3.

Answer (score 0):

Splice removes the element at i from the array, so you need to stay at the current position, if you want to go on iterating normally. As theres an i++ in the for loop, it would normally go one position forward. So you need to go one step backward before to stay at the same position.

```
nums=[3,2,2,3]
val=3;
//first iteration
i=0
current=3//===val
nums.splice(0,1);//nums=[2,2,3]
i--;//i=-1

//next iteration
i++;//i=0
current=2;

//next iteration
i++;//i=1
current=2;

//next iteration
i++;//i=2
current=3;
nums.splice(2,1);//nums=[2,2]
i--;//i=1

//next iteration
i++;//i=2 === nums.length => break
```

In the case [3,2,2,3] it does not matter if you use i++ instead of i-- as it will jump over indexes 1 and 2 wich are not relevant. So this buggy code works by accident...